# Firebase Cloud Functions Error - Cloud Runtime Config is currently experiencing issues, which is preventing your functions from being deployed

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have been hunting down the answer to this particular answer for 2 days with no luck.

I updated the Firebase CLI per their request, and then it was incompatible with my NodeJS, so I had to update that to NodeJS 16. After I did that, I am not able to deploy my functions anymore to Firebase, and just get this non-descript error:

```
Cloud Runtime Config is currently experiencing issues, 
which is preventing your functions from being deployed.
```

I have tried everything I can think of..

- Used NVM to try different versions of Node like 10, 12, 14
- Updated the Engine in the Package JSON to all different versions
- Deleted all my functions from GCP and tried to just reinstall from scratch.

None of those things have done anything to even change the error message, so I have no idea what is going on or even able to see any logs.

I did try to deploy to our STAGING environment and get a different error

```
Error: Failed to load environment variables from .env.:
- Error Key GCLOUD_PROJECT is reserved for internal use.
```

I am not sure what changed with this update, but has anyone else seen/solved this error?

Comment: For now, I was able to roll back my Firebase-Tools-CLI and revert to Node 10, but Has anyone successfully updated their Functions to Node16

Comment: Can you try to reinstall `nodejs` and update firebase-tools? What version of node and firebase tools are you using?

Answer (score 6):

I'm having the same issue, and seems to be related to the project data in gcloud/firebase runtime config data, because I can deploy the same code, in other project.

After downgrading firebase-tools to 11.1.0, the deploy worked as before.

Comment: This worked for me as well. In node v 16.15.1 I had to downgrade to 11.1.0 from 11.2.0.