# Cannot deploy Firebase Function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I am building a flutter project,
when I deploy firebase functions I am getting errors. The errors are not the same they change.
This is the command I've run:

```
firebase deploy --only functions:getOrder
```

Example:

> Error: Cloud Runtime Config is currently experiencing issues, which is preventing your functions from being deployed. Please wait a few minutes and then try to deploy your functions again.
> Run `firebase deploy --except functions` if you want to continue deploying the rest of your project.

Another possible error is:

> Error: Failed to make request to https://serviceusage.googleapis.com/v1/projects/project-name/services/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com

I tried:

```
firebase login --reauth
```

`firebase login` and `firebase logout`

```
firebase use --add
```

Nothing works.

How to solve?
Is there another way to deploy firebase functions?

Comment: The error sounds like it should just be temporary.  [Contact Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact) if you have problems related to temporary errors that don't go away.  Stack Overflow isn't the right place for support issues.

Comment: Try downgrading `firebase-tools` as suggested in [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72862675/18265638) & [link2](https://lightrun.com/answers/firebase-firebase-tools-function-deploy-almost-always-fails-when-deploying-functions-to-new-firebase-project)

Comment: Did this get resolved and go away for you?